# Two buttons form submission with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Hey I have a form with two submit buttons and a simple text input. I want the form to be submitted by ajax (I figured out how to do that).

**form:**

```
<form method='post' action='likesystem.php' id='7'>
<input class='form-control' type='hidden' value='7' name='postid'>

<button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' name='poslike' value='liking'>Like this</button>
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' name='poslike' value='disliking'>Dislike this</button>
```

**the script is as follows:**

```
<script>
$('#7').on('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  url: 'likesystem.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $('#7').serialize(),

});
});
</script>
```

**the php page:**

```
<?php    

require_once 'config.php';

        $link = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

        if(! $link ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Connection Error";
        }

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$postid = $_POST['postid'];


switch($_POST['poslike']) {
    case 'liking':
        $sql = "UPDATE posts SET poslike = poslike + 1 WHERE id = $postid";

    case 'disliking':
        $sql = "UPDATE posts SET dislike = dislike + 1 WHERE id = $postid";

}

if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
            echo "You did something";
        } else {
            echo "There was an error";
        }

mysqli_close($link);
}
```

What I am I doing wrong here? I've checked multiple sites but the answers there could help and that's why I'm asking it here now.

Comment: What were you expecting, vs what you got?

Comment: You should trigger ajax events with `succes/error` callbacks (or `done()/fail()`), your `switch` is wrong, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` is useless..... Read a tutorial and retry because it's very messy for now

Comment: @cHao I expected the database to change but that didnt happen.

Comment: @pirs could you elaborate please?

Comment: Why would you expect the database to change when neither button was clicked (meaning neither value was submitted)?

Comment: I clicked it. I tested it. Both of them in fact.

Comment: enjoy: https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Comment: And what does `$('#7').serialize()` give you? Cause something tells me it can't see that a button was clicked.

Comment: @cHao, all this code is fubar, let him learn a little bit more then he ll understand why is it wrong..

Comment: @pirs I know that bit and that works well but that is not my question, really. My question, if it wasn't stated clear enough is how I can get php to do two different things depending on which button I pressed to submit the form.

Comment: The answer is, your code is all messed up (ajax, sql and php) and you need to read docs.. - or - maybe someone will work for free, but not me.

Comment: and @cHao thank you. As you can tell I am just learning all of this. How could I check what it gives me? It does give me the textbox for sure, because I could change the database with that but when I tried to add the two button functionality it doesn't work anymore. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @pirs well I'm not asking you to work for me. I'm asking you to help.

Comment: Read my first comment, see the doc for each ones (google), then you ll be ok with it

Comment: But your code is very messy from A to Z, you don't need help, you need to read and learn.

Comment: First, do a `print_r($_POST)` and see what is in your array. Your switch will not work if the value is not sent.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard the ajax request worked according to the Console. i have included the jQuery library. No there are no errors reported and I am running this on a web server.

Comment: Did you do the `print_r()` in your PHP script?

Comment: I did include it and it just says "Array()". I guess it didn't post it then?

Comment: That's right - the information has not been posted. .serialize() is not doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: It must have something to do with the event.preventDefault(). My browsers console says that one should no longer use that and instead use "defaultPrevented". If I do that I get redirected to the php page but it works. What is "defaultPrevented"?

Comment: @JayBlanchard how would I then get the value of the button I pressed when .serialize() doesnt do it?

Comment: You have to get the value of the clicked item and add it to the string of data to be posted, just like the answer below shows

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this:

```
<form method='post' action='likesystem.php' id='7'>
    <input class='form-control' type='hidden' value='7' name='postid' id='postid'>

    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm vote' name='poslike' value='liking'>Like this</button>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm vote' name='poslike' value='disliking'>Dislike this</button>

</form>
```

and try this code for script:

```
 <script>
    $('.vote').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var postid = $('#postid').val();
        var poslike = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'likesystem.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'postid=' + postid + '&poslike=' + poslike,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sometimes it posts the request once, other times twice and even four times, why is it doing that? @JayBlanchard

Comment: Will you be please more specific what are you getting in the POST on your action page 'likesystem.php'? @D. Krold